# Use all json entries in my javascript

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have a JSON file with app 200 calculated values. I need all of these inserted in the javascript that calls the JSON file. Any easy function to 'empty' all variables without having to code every single one?

My javascript

```
var values = [];
$.getJSON(
    "data.php",
    { cid: 17, bid: 33 },
    function(json) {
        [What to put here?]
    }       
);
```

And later I use the variables as this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var bipolar = new RGraph.Bipolar({
            id: 'rb-e3-4',
            left:  [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18],
            right: [e19,e20,e21,e22,e23,e24,e25,e26,e27,e28,e29,e30,e31,e32,e33,e34,e35,e36],
            options: {
        margin: 8,
        colors: ['rgb(51,128,182)'],
        noaxes: true,
        xmax: 9,
        xlabels: false,
        gutter: {
                    center: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
                }
    }
        }).draw();
    })
```

My JSON

```
{
"b1": 3,
"b2": 4 [+ 200 other variables]
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many questions, try using the site search.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"I need all of these inserted in the javascript that calls the JSON file."*. It sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @FelixKling I have a page containing a lot of graph elements which needs to be drawn with data from my database. The multiple graphs have more than 200 variables and therefore I need all of this inserted in my javascript. I plan to do all the filtering and calculation in the JSON file in order to limit the data I transfer... Still sound like a bad idea?

Comment: If that means you want to dynamically create more than 200 variables, yes. There is a reason we have collections such as objects and arrays. Since you haven't shown how you are going to use the data, it's difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @FelixKling Appreciate your input :-) I have added more info to my question above

Comment: Thanks for the update! Why are you not already returning the JSON in the needed format? I.e. `{"left": [3, 4, ...], "right": [....]}`?

Answer (score 0):

If its simply pushing every value into the values array, then this would work

```
function (json) {
  for (var key in json) {
    values.push(json[key]);
  }
}
```